# REST API test program on Tomcat v8.5 throws error (eclipse and no eclipse)

Tags: java, rest, tomcat

I am just stuck with this problem. All I ever wanted to do was try out a REST Api so as to start with REST using Jersey jars.
I have a maven project on eclipse with the following jars:
[image]

My web.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
        <display-name>Hello World</display-name>    
        <servlet>  
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>  
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>  
        <init-param>  
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>  
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.examples.helloworld</param-value>  
        </init-param>  
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
      </servlet>  
      <servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>  
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>  
      </servlet-mapping>  

    </web-app>
```

But whenever I run this, I get the following error in the server:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:988)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1860)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name [jersey-serlvet]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMappingDecoded(StandardContext.java:3154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMappingDecoded(StandardContext.java:3145)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureContext(ContextConfig.java:1376)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1190)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:775)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5105)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more


org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [XXXXXX\webapps\helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:756)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:988)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1860)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can anyone please help?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Although it says "Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name [jersey-serlvet]", I checked my web.xml for the correctness of names. It all seems fine

Comment: You wanted to post `web.xml`, but posted `pom.xml`.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. Corrected!

Comment: I just tried out with your `web.xml` and it works. Deployed on Tomcat 8.5.5. If the problem still exists, post your pom.xml and I'll check it.

Comment: @ujulu Hi, I think I was missing theservlet container jars. Now it works!